# Tkinter изменение значения Scale и Label кнопкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scale

Мне необходимо в Tkinter изменять значение Label изменением Scale и нажатием Button.
С изменением Scale все получило, значение меняется. Для этого создал переменную var1.
А вот с изменением по кнопке не получается. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с аналогичным?

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
scale = Scale

var1 = DoubleVar()
label1 = Label(window, relief='groove', width=6)
scale1 = Scale(window, variable=var1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scene1Btn = Button(window)


# geometry
label1.grid()
scene1Btn.grid()
scale1.grid(row=0, column=1)



# Scene recall function
# Button Command
def recall1():
#    global var1 = 10
    pass


# Initialize buttons
window.title("button")
label1.configure(textvariable=var1)
scene1Btn.configure(text='Recall1', command=recall1)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Понял. Достаточно изменить значение `Scale`:

```
Scale1.set(число)
```